# Проблема MS SQL 2005 Delphi ошибка "Недостаточные или неполные сведения о ключевом столбце"

Tags: delphi, sql-server

Доброго времени суток! 
У меня поднят MS SQL Server 2005. 
Подключаюсь к нему Delphi через AdoQuery. По началу все происходило хорошо до определённого момента.

```
ADOQuery1.Active:=false;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('Select * From Consumption');
ADOQuery1.Active:=true;
for i:=1 to ADOQuery1.RecordCount do
  begin
    ADOQuery1.Edit;
    ADOQuery1.FieldByName('DT').AsDateTime:=StrToDateTime(FormatDateTime('dd.mm.yyyy        hh:mm:ss', StrToDateTime('17.08.2013 11:00:00')));
    ADOQuery1.Post;
    ADOQuery1.Next; 
  end;
```

ошибка "**Недостаточные или неполные сведения о ключевом столбце. Обновление влияет на слишком большое число строк.**"  Ошибка возникает во время *ADOQuery1.Post*
Гуглил, Microsoft пишет что якобы их косяк и его исправляет SP4 MS SQL 2000
но у меня MS SQL 2005 SP2 Кто сталкивался с подобным??? поделитесь опытом плиз...

Comment: опыт подсказывает, что так писать вообще не правильно. 

1. если вы изменяете у всех записей одно поле и притом на одно и то же значение, то почему бы не сделать просто update. 
2. цикл по результату запрос делают через `while not ADOQuery1.Eof do`, а не через цикл до RecordCount.

Comment: Не вижу принципиальной разницы между циклом For и While мне цикл For нужен для контроля счетчика (i) так как в дальнейшем этот счетчик используется, но ошибка выходит именно в этом участке кода.